# show that the equation $3z^3+(2-3ai)z^2+(6+2bi)z+4=0$has exactly one real root

Tags: complex-numbers, recurrence-relations

> show that :
>
> the equation $3z^3+(2-3ai)z^2+(6+2bi)z+4=0$ (where both $a$ and $b$ are real numbers) has exactly one real root.

let $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}$ be root,and $$x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}=-\frac{4}{3},x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}=\dfrac{3ai-2}{3},x_{1}x_{2}+x_{1}x_{3}+x_{2}x_{3}=\dfrac{2bi+6}{3}$$

Comment: For this Complex coefficient I can't deal it

Comment: Well, you know that $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are the three roots of the cubic. You also have 3 equations relating these roots. So you might be able to solve these three equations for  $x_1, x_2, x_3$ say using substitution? And you should find that only one of them is real.

Comment: Parallel to method which @okrzysik said, If you want the answer just for polynomials of degree 3, you can solve them and reach to your real root. (There is a formula for degree 3 roots like degree two.)

Answer (score 1):

If we had exactly 3 real roots, then the sum of all roots would be real, but it is not.

If we had exactly 2 real roots, then the product of all roots would not be real, but it is.